# How can I save NSWindow programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Basically I got an array of allocated windows and want to save their state (position/size/subviews) when the app is closed. Is there any way to do this?

When I try to use a NSUserDefault i get this error message: Attempt to set a non-property-list. Which turns out to that you can't save NSWindows in a user default. Should i use this instead?

```
 //customView
 [self setFrameAutosaveName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.tag]];
```

Comment: What does 'saving NSWindows' mean in English?  You mean, saving its position and size?

Comment: Are you making a document-based app?

Answer (score 1):

It's not usually useful to save the positions and size of subviews in a window.

Using `setFrameAutosaveName:` will save the window's position and size for a given name. The next time your app opens a document and creates a window with that autosave name, its state should be restored.

As for the size and positions of subviews, they are usually automatically laid out based on the auto layout system, or using Struts and Springs. Either that, or their positions and sizes are derived from data in your document model. Either way, you don't generally need to save them yourself. Why do you think you should be saving them? What are you trying to accomplish by saving them?